# Docker compose nginx config setup to broadcast on port 8000

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn, alpine-linux

I am at the end of a project where I have an Nginx as a router in a docker container that works with a test node app on port 8000, but I need it to point to another Nginx Docker compose container which is setup to run a Django app. I don't think the second Nginx is configured right to run the app on port 8000, and am looking for any advise as this.

Basically I've been following two separate tutorials and this is where they meet.

Here are the files that I think you'll need but feel free to ask for anything additional.

docker-compose.prod.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./dcahill
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn dcahill.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/dchll/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/dchll/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/dchll/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/dchll/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

nginx.conf (not he main router directing public traffic to 8000)

```
upstream dcahill.com {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass dcahill.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/dchll/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/dchll/web/mediafiles/;
    }

}
server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    location / {
        proxy_pass dcahill.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/dchill/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/dchll/web/mediafiles/;
    }

}
```

My main nginx router config that works for the test node appis big but these are the only settings apart from the SSL and default html5 boilerplate:

```
# Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.dcahill.com dcahill.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Listen for requests for dcahill on port 443 and return server open on port 8000
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name dcahill.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://111.222.111.222:8000;
}
}

# Listen for requests for dcahill on port 443 and return server open on port 8000
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  www.dcahill.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://111.222.111.222:8000;
    }
}
```

My test node script which runs fine is as follows

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 8000

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
  console.log('received request')
  response.end('Hello from app1!')
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.listen(port, (err) => {
  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example docker-compose config is mapping port `8000` to `80`, and then the NGINX config is redirecting port 80 to 443 which is not being provided externally.

Your NGINX service needs to make port 80 and 443 into the container (it is listening on those ports).

```
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/dchll/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/dchll/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web
```

The NGINX service will then be reverse proxied to your app on port 8000 within the Docker container, but port 8000 will not be available externally.

Comment: Really appreciate the quick detailed reply. I am getting the following error when doing a fresh build at the very end.
`
    ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ******_nginx_1 (e585cda3d9d970ee4c0ae6fa64f61b8c2e56722c67e302f94012695274cecf17): Bind for 0.0.0.0:443 failed: port is already allocated
`
I did a docker-compose down -v beforehand.

Comment: @DesCahill that means something else is already running on port 443 on your system.

Comment: Yes I am using 443 in my main nginx router as its managing the lets envncript SSL certs, but I need to keep that.
Why does the port have 443:443 what is the one on the left and one on the right, and can I do a translation here or use a different port altogether?

Comment: @DesCahill Your NGINX config is listening on port 443. If you are proxying to it from something else you should probably use a different port and set the `Https` header.

Comment: I don't think I even need https at this stage as the certs are all managed from the main nginx router which is on the same physical server in another docker container. Pretty lost at this stage but its the final hurdle. Maybe my nginx.conf just needs to listen on 8000 instead of 443 ssl

The main router was setup according to this video:
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrZ2NocN2pk&list=PLjwDNSlPlIIunYlhIRuftmmPmMZlze6WJ&index=16)[link]  which works

and the django app from the following
[link](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/)[link]

Comment: @DesCahill that's what I meant - if you are handling the SSL certs externally you should proxy the requests to a different port (not 443) and then set the `Https` header to let your app know that it is being proxied from an SSL connection.

Comment: Thanks, I thought `proxy_redirect off;` would do the https header, but I am not sure that's the case and I cant find any good info online. In relation to the port I have changed it to 1337:80, as that's what the tutorial I was following had but I don't see any other reference to that number in the tutorial, so don't think its right.

Comment: @DesCahill that would be fine, you basically need to map some port on your computer to some port into the docker container, and then the docker containers can communicate internally on different ports.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I havent figured it out, and think I need to find someone who knows Alpine, Django, Gunicorn, Docker, and Nginx to look over everything to find out whats going on. I know its a tall order but I have completely exhausted my own knowledge at the final hurdle, and really dont wanna go near Apache or Tomcat.